# Basic Python Question on String operations: example: string.lowercase

Tags: python, string, operations, attributeerror

So I'm trying to run this, but it errors out and I need help understanding what's wrong. I really appreciate any help, I'm taking the MIT opencourseware intro to programming:

```
words="GreatTimes"
words.lowercase
```

And I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lowercase'
```

The issue is that I'm trying to run example code from "How to think like a computer scientist" and it still gives me the error.

```
def isLower(ch):
    return string.find(string.lowercase, ch) != -1
```

So I can't figure out what the syntax error is. Looking at the [Python doc page](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html) it says this:

> string.lowercase A string containing
>   all the characters that are considered
>   lowercase letters. On most systems
>   this is the string
>   'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'. The
>   specific value is locale-dependent,
>   and will be updated when
>   locale.setlocale() is called.

Thoughts?

Edit:
Ah, sorry I should be more clear. So I'm trying to write a piece of code that will tell me whether or not a character in a string is lowercase or not. my code is my implementation of it. while the example code is something i'm using to try to check to see if my syntax is wrong and that is the source of the problem. However, the example code also generates an error. In a nutshell, why doesn't this code work? It seems like it Should spit out a string of all the lowercase letters like "reatimes" from "GreatTimes" And/or how would you use string.lowercase to make this program?

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by what you are trying to do. This seems like a rather contrived exercise.

- If you just want to use an instance method, `words.lower()` will return a lowercase version of the string `words`.
- If you want to implement a lowercase function of your own using `string.lowercase` (which is just a constant set to a string of all lowercase letters), then you need to make sure you do an `import string` before calling it (e.g. in your `lower` function example).
- If you did an `import string`, you could also use `string.lower('STRING with CAPS')` instead.

Edit: Here's some code that runs your function, to show you it works:

```
import string

def isLower(ch):
    return string.find(string.lowercase, ch) != -1


words = "GreatTimes"

lowercase_letters = ""
for ch in words:
    print ch, '->', isLower(ch)

    if isLower(ch):
        lowercase_letters += ch

print "Lowercase letters were:", lowercase_letters
```

Output:

```
G -> False
r -> True
e -> True
a -> True
t -> True
T -> False
i -> True
m -> True
e -> True
s -> True
Lowercase letters were: reatimes
```

Comment: Thank your for your help thus far and sorry about not being clearer. Basically I'm trying to write a piece of code that will tell me whether or not a character in a string is lowercase or not using string.lowercase. But import string at the top of the program still gives me the same error.

Comment: okay, so I actually tried your program and there were Many problems initially. I was using python 3.2, Sooooo I decided to give python 2.7 a try. And it worked! So at least I have something to look at and play with now. *moments later AH! Everything works now in 2.7. Before I ran string.lowercase and it said string was not defined even with using import string. I can see now that string.lowercase is like a tuple with all the lowercase words. So I can use it to compare my letter with the list and see if there is a match! Thank you very much. As soon as I can upvote... with 15 rep.

Answer (score 0):

lowercase is the name of a string in the string module:

> > > import string
> > >       string.lowercase
> > >       'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

but you can't access it through a string instance:

> > > word = 'this is a string'
> > >       word.lowercase
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lowercase'

Also, the find method doesn't do what you think -- check the docs.

Allen

Answer (score -2):

Try to use "ascii.lowercase" it works