# How to remove punctuation and capitalization in my palindrome assignment?

Tags: python, string, windows, jupyter-notebook, palindrome

The problem is trying to use strings to prove whether a word or phrase is a palindrome.

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):

    left = 0

    right = len(input_string) - 1

    while left < right:
        if input_string[left] != input_string[right]:
            return False
        left += 1
        right -= 1
    
    return True
```

This what I attempted to do but when typing in
my_palindrome("race car") it was proven false when it is supposed to be proven true. Need help on finding code to add to this to make punctuation and capitalization negligible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove punctuation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664775/how-to-remove-punctuation-in-python)

Comment: To remove spaces - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string, to lowercase - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067692/basic-python-question-on-string-operations-example-string-lowercase

Answer (score 1):

For characters that aren't letters, there is a string function called `.isalpha()` that returns `True` if the string contains only alphabetic characters, `False` otherwise. You'll need to iterate over each character of the string, retaining only the characters that pass this check.

To make your function case-insensitive, you can use `.upper()` or `.lower()`, which returns the string with all the letters upper/lowercased, respectively.

<sub>Note that this answer is deliberately incomplete, (i.e. no code), per the recommendations [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). If, after several days from the posting of this answer, you're still stuck, post a comment and I can advise further.</sub>